# NLog displays 'lambda_method' instead of logger name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, nlog

Here's the layout renderer string I'm using:

```
layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger:shortName=True}|${aspnet-Request-UserAgent}|${message} ${exception:format=toString,Data:maxInnerExceptionLevel=10}"
```

With the relevant section being: `${logger:shortName=True}`

This seems to work fine when I build and run debug version of the project in IIS:

```
2019-09-10 08:50:20.8863|INFO|AuthenticationController|39 Win8-64 8.4.0.18|username='testuser' /api/v1/authenticate
```

But when I run production version, I end up with the following instead:

```
2019-09-10 08:50:20.8863|INFO|lambda_method|39 Win8-64 8.4.0.18|username='testuser' /api/v1/authenticate
```

Instead of getting the actual short logger name (AuthenticationController), I end up with lambda_method.

I obtain the logger as following:

```
private readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

This is inside ASP.NET Core 2.2 project, with NLog.Web.AspNetCore version 4.8.4.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you add static to `private readonly Logger _logger` so it becomes`private static readonly Logger _logger` ?

Comment: If the `static` wont help, please show the output of `${stacktrace}`

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3630

Answer (score 2):

Try updating to NLog ver. 4.6.8:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog

It tries to scan for a better logger-name, when meeting "lambda_method".

Comment: I'm using NLog.Web.AspNetCore nuget, and that one hasn't been updated since: Friday, October 11, 2019 (10/11/2019), so I don't think the fix is in it.  The version you're recommending (plain NLog) has been released 3 weeks later: Monday, November 4, 2019 (11/4/2019)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having `NLog` and `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` installed side-by-side for the same project. Actually it is recommended since `NLog` is updated more often.

Comment: Won't I end up with two different NLog.dll's if I do that?

Comment: No the deploy / output-folder for the project will contain the NLog-dll from the direct NLog-dependency instead of the transient NLog-dependency (coming from NLog.Web.AspNetCore).